# Gitlab Runner setup issues on Mac Mini with M2 processor

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, macos

I have a pair of Mac Minis with M2 processors that I am trying to setup as runners on a locally hosted gitlab setup. For a variety of other systems I simply followed the instructions on the runners page. When I select Mac and Arm64 here are the instructions I see:

> Download and install binary

```
# Download the binary for your system
sudo curl --output /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-darwin-arm64`

# Give it permission to execute
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner

# The rest of the commands execute as the user who will run the runner
# Register the runner (steps below), then run
cd ~
gitlab-runner install
gitlab-runner start
```

> Command to register runner

```
gitlab-runner register --url https://gitlab.blacktoppstudios.com/ --registration-token Fj3n5ngFakeToken
```

I needed to create the output folder for the download from AWS, but that seemed to work. But when I try to do `gitlab-runner start` I get the following error:

> FATAL: Failed to start gitlab-runner: exit status 134

I couldn't see any results for exist status 134. A number of people had issues with the log files not being writable. I tried setting permissions on the log files and get the same error. If I change the log file location there is no apparent effect also.

I tried to perform the registration step and this appeared to work and create the toml file but didn't change the error message.

If I copy the command out of the file plist file at `~/Library/LaunchAgents/gitlab-runner.plist` and add `--debug` I get this command:

> % /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner --debug run --working-directory /Users/cisadmin  --config /Users/cisadmin/.gitlab-runner/config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog

and that gives me this:

```
Runtime platform                                    arch=arm64 os=darwin pid=2562 revision=436955cb version=15.11.0
Starting multi-runner from /Users/cisadmin/.gitlab-runner/config.toml...  builds=0
Checking runtime mode                               GOOS=darwin uid=501
WARNING: Running in user-mode.                     
WARNING: Use sudo for system-mode:                 
WARNING: $ sudo gitlab-runner...                   
                                                   
Configuration loaded                                builds=0
listenaddress: ""
sessionserver:
  listenaddress: ""
  advertiseaddress: ""
  sessiontimeout: 1800
concurrent: 1
checkinterval: 0
loglevel: null
logformat: null
user: ""
runners: []
sentrydsn: null
modtime: 2023-05-09T16:43:47.632488987-05:00
loaded: true
shutdowntimeout: 0
  builds=0
Waiting for stop signal                             builds=0
listen_address not defined, metrics & debug endpoints disabled  builds=0
[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0
Initializing executor providers                     builds=0
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
Starting worker                                     builds=0 worker=0
Feeding runners to channel                          builds=0
```

The `listen_address not defined` has me concerned but I have no further insight into what this means or how to troubleshoot it. I would appreciate any insight on how to approach `Failed to start gitlab-runner: exit status 134`.

EDIT - Some Docs suggested that local terminal have different permissions somehow than ssh connections. Well I tried following the steps from a local prompt and rebooted and now `gitlab-runner status` says that it is running, but it still isn't showing as connected from the runners listing  on the gitlab web ui.

I looked into the config.toml and it is missing the [[runners]] section. I tried creating one by copying and adapting from a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several errors.

1. The log files weren't writable. Either set permissions or change to some writable place. I set it `/Users/$USERNAME/.gitlab-runner/gitlab-runner.{out,err}.log`
2. Ran the bootstrap commands the local terminal suggested that ssh never presented even with identical commands. (I hate this, I have no clue why it is different, but it is).
3. Copied the [[runners]] section from the `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` to `/Users/$USERNAME/.gitlab-runner/config.toml`.

After that I issude `gitlab-runner stop` and `gitlab-runner start` and checked the GitLab web UI and the runners were connected.